# What does `this` refer to?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript class:

```
function Person(n){
  // ...
}
```

Outside of the class, I have the following code:

```
Person.prototype.shower = function(){ this.dirtFactor=2 }
```

What does `this` in the above code refer to? Does it refer to `prototype`, or to the `Person` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, basics first: when you write `function Person(o) { ... }`, you are **not** declaring a class -- JavaScript does not class based, but *object based*. This statement simply declares a function (which incidentally, are objects as well).

Next, when you create an object like this:

```
var mellon = new Person('Mellon');
```

you are creating an object, whose constructor (of sorts) is `Person`.

Now, read this carefully: since `mellon`'s constructor is `Person`, all methods in `Person`'s `prototype` will be available in the object.

So if you write:

```
Person.prototype.shower = function(){ this.dirtFactor=2 }
```

then the method `mellon.shower()` will be available.

I recommend going through [Mozilla's intro to OOP in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) for some details on this topic.

---

So to answer your question: `this` refers to the object with which the method `shower` was invoked. In the above case, it would be `mellon`.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of `this` depends on how you *call* the function, not how you define it.

Assuming you do something like:

```
var bob = new Person('whatever n is');
bob.shower();
```

Then `this` will be `bob` (which will be an instance of `Person`).

Comment: +1, but to be clear, `this` refers to whatever was before the `.` when called. If called without a `.`, then `this` defaults to `window` / `global`.

Comment: Which can be proved by replacing the shower function with `function() { console.log(this); }`.

Comment: @Box9 `this` refers to the current context. `this` will refer to the `window` object (in a browser) by default. The context changes as you add enclosures/functions.

Comment: @kim3er, no, the current context depends solely on how the function is called (as David already mentioned). It is not affected by whether or not it is inside another function. Try `(bob.shower)()` with your `console.log` version of `shower`.

Comment: @Box9 That statement is not at odds with what I said. `this` defaults to the highest context. The context can however by manipulated using `apply` and `call` functions to specify your own context. In you example though, the context is the instantiation of the Person function. This can be tested by using `console.log` or alike.

Comment: @Box9 Apologies, I assumed you were the original questioner. Otherwise I wouldn't have attempted to clarify you position.

Comment: @kim3er, sorry my example should have been: `var a; (a = bob.shower)()`, and my point is that the context is changed by the dot notation, not by the nesting of any functions.

Comment: @Box9 I maybe missing something and I suspect we're both trying to say the same thing. But, your example appears to prove my original point. The context (`this`) has been altered as a result of wrapping `bob.shower` in an enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the instance of the person

So when you do a
`var Mike = new Person();`

then this is Mike

Example

```
<input type="text" id="field" value="Bla" />
<script>
document.getElementById('field').onfocus=function() { 
  alert(this.value)
}
</script>
```

will alert the value of the field the function is assigned to

Answer (score 1):

It reffers to a instance of Person class

```
   var instance = new Person( ... );

   instance.shower(); // Here will be this.dirtFactor assigned to instance.dirtFactor
```

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the object upon which `shower` is called. Specifically, you will eventually end up doing

```
 p = new Person(n);
```

This will execute the `Person` function and create a new, empty object which will be accessible as `this` in the constructor. That object will then be given a link to `Person.prototype` and any attribute references that fail on `p` will look on `Person.prototype` to see if it's found there.

If it's called on `p`, using `p.shower()`, then `this` will return to `p`. The point is though that there aren't instances and classes in javascript. `Person.prototype` is one object and all objects that are constructed by `Person` will share a reference to it.

Removing prototypes all together, you can just do

```
 person = {'shower': function () { 
     this.dirtFactor = 2; }
 }

 person.shower();
 console.log(person.dirtFactor);
```

and you will see that `this` still refers to the object upon which you called the method.